# How to fix arrays full of zero, even after apparent nonzero initialized?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm attempting to create an array of random integers that **do not repeat**. Instead, my array is full of zeroes. We aren't allowed to use things from the outside of our learning such as ArrayList or Arrays class and such. (Pisses me off but I make do).

I haven't tried any other method different as I am still VERY novice, but i've used little iterators and output checkpoints to see what is happening much easier. The random values are initialized but are just not stored.

```
private Card[] returnShuffled(Card[] cards) {
    Card[] shuffled = cards;                        //Card array
    int[] randomIndexes = new int[cards.length];    //Random ?>NONREPEATING integer array.
    int randomValue;                                //Value entered into Random Indexes.
    for(int x = 0; x < randomIndexes.length; x++) {
        do {
        randomValue = (int) (Math.random()*52);
            System.out.println(randomValue);
        } while(!(search(randomIndexes, randomValue)>-1));
        randomIndexes[x] = randomValue;             //Point of problem: Printing out the Array after loop gives a list of 0s
    }
    for(int x = 0; x < shuffled.length; x++) {
        shuffled[x] = cards[randomIndexes[x]];
    }
    return shuffled;
}

private int search(int[] random, int value) {
int token = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < random.length; i++) {
        if(random[i]==value) {
            token = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return token;
}
```

Comment: The usual way to do this is to initialize the array with `[0,1,2,3,.....]` and then randomly shuffle it. You could also just shuffle the original card array. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array

Comment: Your two variables `shuffled`and `cards` actually point to the same physical array. This causes all kinds of unwanted effects when you do `shuffled[x] = cards[randomIndexes[x]]`. But rethink the problem, there is a much simpler approach to do shuffling.

Comment: Yes, `Math.random` can easily give repeated values.  The correct (easy) way to do this is just to shuffle the `Card[]` array.

Comment: `randomIndexes` is initialized with `0`s so you should add `1` to the generated number and also ignore `0` in your search for repeated numbers. Then when populating `shuffled`, you should deduct 1 from the `cards[]` array element. Also, like what other people mentioned, there are much more straightforward approaches to this.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I just redid the entire code after looking up dozens of other people's examples. I think i boxed myself in by attempting to not make use of temporary arrays/objects.